# Word statistics files not found! HTTP Error 404: Not Found in ekphrasis Library

Tags: python

I have been using ekphrasis for a long time and there has been no problem but recently when I run my code in google Colab again I get this error that I can't download this file(Word statistics files) and can't use the TextPreProcessor() function anymore. how can I fix this problem?

```
Word statistics files not found!
Downloading... 
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
HTTPError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-08f51e048e36> in <module>()
     12 import re
     13 
---> 14 text_processor=TextPreProcessor()
     15 ##### text preprocessor for ekphrasis
     16 text_processor = TextPreProcessor(

16 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ekphrasis/classes/preprocessor.py in __init__(self, **kwargs)
     92             self.segmenter = Segmenter(corpus=self.segmenter_corpus)
     93         if self.mode != "fast":
---> 94             self.spell_corrector = SpellCorrector(corpus=self.corrector_corpus)
     95 
     96         self.regexes = ExManager().get_compiled()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ekphrasis/classes/spellcorrect.py in __init__(self, corpus)
     21         """
     22         super().__init__()
---> 23         self.WORDS = Counter(read_stats(corpus, 1))
     24         self.N = sum(self.WORDS.values())
     25 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ekphrasis/utils/helpers.py in read_stats(corpus, ngram)
     45 def read_stats(corpus, ngram):
     46     stats_dir = get_stats_dir()
---> 47     check_stats_files()
     48     print("Reading " + "{} - {}grams ...".format(corpus, ngram))
     49     text = path.join(*[stats_dir, corpus, "counts_{}grams.txt".format(ngram)])

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ekphrasis/utils/helpers.py in check_stats_files()
     88     stats_dir = get_stats_dir()
     89     if not os.path.exists(stats_dir) or len(listdir_nohidden(stats_dir)) == 0:
---> 90         download_statistics()
     91 
     92 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/ekphrasis/utils/helpers.py in download_statistics()
     74     print("Word statistics files not found!\nDownloading...", end=" ")
     75     url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/a84otqrg6u1c5je/stats.zip?dl=1"
---> 76     urlretrieve(url, "stats.zip")
     77     print("done!")
     78 

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in urlretrieve(url, filename, reporthook, data)
    245     url_type, path = splittype(url)
    246 
--> 247     with contextlib.closing(urlopen(url, data)) as fp:
    248         headers = fp.info()
    249 

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    220     else:
    221         opener = _opener
--> 222     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    223 
    224 def install_opener(opener):

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    640             response = self.parent.error(
--> 641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 
    643         return response

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    561             http_err = 0
    562         args = (dict, proto, meth_name) + args
--> 563         result = self._call_chain(*args)
    564         if result:
    565             return result

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    501         for handler in handlers:
    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 503             result = func(*args)
    504             if result is not None:
    505                 return result

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_302(self, req, fp, code, msg, headers)
    753         fp.close()
    754 
--> 755         return self.parent.open(new, timeout=req.timeout)
    756 
    757     http_error_301 = http_error_303 = http_error_307 = http_error_302

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    529         for processor in self.process_response.get(protocol, []):
    530             meth = getattr(processor, meth_name)
--> 531             response = meth(req, response)
    532 
    533         return response

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_response(self, request, response)
    639         if not (200 <= code < 300):
    640             response = self.parent.error(
--> 641                 'http', request, response, code, msg, hdrs)
    642 
    643         return response

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in error(self, proto, *args)
    567         if http_err:
    568             args = (dict, 'default', 'http_error_default') + orig_args
--> 569             return self._call_chain(*args)
    570 
    571 # XXX probably also want an abstract factory that knows when it makes

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    501         for handler in handlers:
    502             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 503             result = func(*args)
    504             if result is not None:
    505                 return result

/usr/lib/python3.7/urllib/request.py in http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs)
    647 class HTTPDefaultErrorHandler(BaseHandler):
    648     def http_error_default(self, req, fp, code, msg, hdrs):
--> 649         raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
    650 
    651 class HTTPRedirectHandler(BaseHandler):

HTTPError: HTTP Error 404: Not Found
```

you can see that the URL address does not exist anymore.

```
url = "https://www.dropbox.com/s/a84otqrg6u1c5je/stats.zip?dl=1"
```

**Update:**

as @Kris mentioned in the comment, the official repository steel did not fix this problem but on the discussed page some of the forks change the URL link, so they can be helpful until the official version solves the error. One of the forks that could be used  is:

```
!pip install git+https://github.com/fucaja/ekphrasis.git
```

Comment: Well if the URL does not exist, 404 is normal. Who is giving this URL ?

Comment: And there is already a discussion in the official repo https://github.com/cbaziotis/ekphrasis/issues/28

Comment: Since the issue is open in the official repo, I think you should wait for their response.